# Node and npm version locking for frontend framework projects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a frontend project in React and another in Vue where other developers will be making pushes to the repo.  I am using a set version of node and npm but what is the best way to enforce these versions for other developers so that the js bundles they build will be using the same?  We currently don't have a proper build process so the build of the bundles are just done through the command line (e.g. `npm build production`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a engines property in package.json and can use "engineStrict": true in order to enforce it.

```
{
  "engineStrict": true,
  "engines": { 
    "node" : ">=0.10.3 <0.12",
    "npm" : "~1.0.20"
}
```

go one directory up and then install it like - npm install myproject that will trigger the checks for engines and engineStrict.

If the particular versions are not present then it will throw error.

However engineStrict was removed in npm 3.0.0 so you can use npm --engine-strict=true from command line.

Comment: thanks atul!  What happens if a collaborator doesn't have these versions install?  Does it just install them for them and switches to them or does it throw an error ?